# Using expect in bash to execute a command with a password request

Tags: bash, password, expect

I have worked for a while on making a `BASH` script to go through two lists and creating a command out of it.

In the end it should execute the command and synchronize my ZFS server and ZFS backup server.

Only pinnacle is that `BASH` cant actually insert a password when a command ask's for it.

To my understanding this can be achieved with `expect`.

The command is stored in `$ExecuteSyncoid`
And would look like this

```
/usr/sbin/syncoid <UserName>@<IP>:Storage/WallaBag Storage/Docker/WallaBag --compress none --sshcipher chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com --sshport <PortNumber> --sshkey </dest/to/keyfile> --no-privilege-elevation
```

The password is stored in `$PWD`

now i have to execute the `expect` from within BASH since im not really in the mood to try and recreate all the code in `expect/tcl` which i have never tried before.

The `expect` part is

```
Enter passphrase for key '<nameOfKey>'
```

---

Now i dont understand `tcl/expect`
But I have made the attempts so far and i just cant make it work even one time

```
expect -c 'expect "Enter" { spawn $ExecuteCommand; send -- "$PWD\r"; interact }'


expect -c 'spawn $ExecuteSyncoid; expect "Enter"; send -- "$PWD\r"; interact'


syncoid command/password
/usr/bin/expect - <<EOF
    spawn $ExecuteSyncoid
    expect "Enter"
    send -- "$PWD\r"
EOF


/usr/bin/expect <<EOD
spawn $ExecuteSyncoid
expect "Enter passphrase for key"
send -- "$PWD\r"
interact
EOD


/usr/bin/expect -c 'expect "Enter" { spawn $ExecuteSyncoid; send -- "$PWD\r" }'
```

---

I Allso attempted to make a seperate script

```
expect -f ./SynCoid-IterateThroughDataSets.exp $ExecuteSyncoid $PWD
```

With the code

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f 
set ExecuteSyncoid [lindex $argv 0];
set PWD [lindex $argv 1];
spawn $ExecuteSyncoid
expect "Enter"
send "\$PWD\r"
```

But unfortunately i cant figure out how to make expect see the `$ExecuteSyncoid` command as one consistent command.
It wont execute it if i put it in quotos "" and if i dont have it in quotes the `$ExecuteSyncoid` bash variable is considered multiple arguments in expect.

---

If anyone knows how to fix this,
Or have an idea about what to do i would appreciate it.

Would allso be great if i could sse the output of the `expect` command as it executes `$ExecuteSyncoid`

Best Regards,
Darkyere

Comment: "_The password is stored in $PWD_" no it's not - that's a reserved variable for the current directory. Use a different (lowercased) variable name, and double quote your variables when you use them in a shell script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not going to review every variant. However shell variables don't expand within single quotes.

Looking at the last variation:

The shell part

```bsh
ExecuteSyncoid="/usr/sbin/syncoid <UserName>@<IP>:Storage/WallaBag Storage/Docker/WallaBag --compress none --sshcipher chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com --sshport <PortNumber> --sshkey </dest/to/keyfile> --no-privilege-elevation"
PassWord="abc123"      # Don't use PWD!

expect -f ./SynCoid-IterateThroughDataSets.exp $ExecuteSyncoid $PassWord
```

Because the variables are not quoted, they experience [Word Splitting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Word-Splitting): expect script will see 13 arguments, not 2.

Always quote your variables:

```bsh
expect -f ./SynCoid-IterateThroughDataSets.exp "$ExecuteSyncoid" "$PassWord"
```

The expect part

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f 
set ExecuteSyncoid [lindex $argv 0];
set PWD [lindex $argv 1];          # this has nothing to do with the shell's PWD variable
spawn $ExecuteSyncoid
expect "Enter"
send "\$PWD\r"
```

Now that the shell variables are quoted, the expect variable `ExecuteSyncoid` is a single word that contains spaces.

The `spawn` command will need that word expanded, so we'll use Tcl's [Argument expansion](http://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/Tcl.htm#M9) syntax:

```
spawn {*}$ExecuteSyncoid
```

You don't want to escape the expect PWD variable when you send it: remove the first backslash

```
send "$PWD\r"
```

And unless you do something else in expect, after you send the password, the expect script will exit and that will kill the syncoid process. The last line of the expect script should be one of:

- if you, the human, need to interact with syncoid

  ```
  interact
  ```
- if you don't need to interact

  ```
  expect eof
  ```

Comment: Thank you alot for this.
This made the script work and i finally synced my ZFS test's machines.
I would never have figured out the part about `{*}$ExecuteSyncoid` TCL's parameter expansion. And wouldten have guessed `$PWD` would have been considered a shell variable. I just thought i created my own variable honestly.
It was a great step forward for my ZFS replication backup.
I highly appreciate it. Thank you :)